# Expected number of coin flips until either 10 more Hs than Ts or 7 more Ts than Hs

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

**Problem:** Find the expected number of flips of a fair coin needed to either have 10 more heads flipped than tails or 7 more tails flipped than heads.

**My approach:**

Let H be the number of heads flipped and T be the number of tails

> $E(H = T + 10) + E(T = H + 7)$

I tried forming a sum of Geometric Progression individually for both cases, but couldn't arrive at the correct answer.

**Follow up**: The interesting fact is that the answer is 70. Is it by pure coincidence that its a product of 7 and 10, or is there a probabilistic reason as to why the expected value comes out to be so conveniently related to the input data?

Comment: It is a consequence of the easy $(a+1)(b-1)+(a-1)(b+1)=2ab-2$ which appears here as $ab=1+\frac12(a+1)(b-1)+\frac12(a-1)(b+1)$ as the only finite solution to a recurrence.

Comment: @Henry please consider explaining your equations. It is very difficult to understand your comment. What is the recurrence? What "consequence of the easy" are you talking about?

Comment: Suppose you are $a$ away from the target number of heads ahead and $b$ away from the target number of heads ahead, and $E(a,b)$ is the expected number of flips until you stop.  Then if you flip a coin, you count a flip and move to a different position so $E(a,b) =1 +\frac12E(a+1,b-1)+ \frac12E(a-1,b+1)$ with $E[a+b,0)=E(0,a+b)=0$.  The only finite solution to this is $E(a,b)=ab$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H_t$ and $T_t$ be the number of heads and tails, respectively, after $t$ flips; let $D_t := H_t - T_t$ be their difference. You now want to look at the first time $T$ that $D_t$ reaches either $+10$ or $-7$:

$$ T = \inf\bigl\{ t \ge 0 \mid D_t \in \{+10, -7\} \bigr\}. $$

Observe that $D$ steps up by $+1$ with probability $\tfrac12$ and down by $-1$ with probability $\tfrac12$; that is, $D$ is just a simple random walk!

So, we have reduced the question to one of hitting time for SRW. This is a very well-known problem, called [Gambler's ruin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin). You can find the expected value $\mathbb E(T)$ of $T$ by searching for this online.

You can calculate it directly using standard hitting-time techniques. Let $X$ be simple random walk on $[0,n] \cap \mathbb Z$; we will be interested in $n = a+b$ and starting from $a$. Let $T$ be the first hitting time of either $0$ or $n$ and $t_i := \mathbb E_i(T)$, ie the expected hitting time started from $i$. Then,

$$ t_i = 1 + \tfrac12 t_{i-1} + \tfrac12 t_{i+1}, \quad t_0 = 0 \quad\text{and}\quad t_n = 0. $$

Solving this relation gives $t_i = i(n-i)$. You should verify this yourself, too! Now, we care about an interval of length $a+b = n$ and starting $a$ from one side, so the time we're interested in is

$$ \mathbb E_a(T) = a \bigl( (a+b) - a \bigr) = ab. $$

You can also prove this using *martingales*. An introduction to these is given in [Section 4.1 of Norris's book](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejames/Markov/s41.pdf). In particular, your exact question is answered on Page 117, at the very end of Section 4.1. You can also find many more expositions online. In particular, if $+10$ is replaced by $+b$ and $-7$ by $-a$, then, indeed, $\mathbb E_0(T) = ab$, the product, as you noticed.